# How to update sequelize on a big project?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have an enormous project that is running on old NodeJS 8.x and I'm currently updating this project to work on NodeJS 14.x, do you have any advice how can I proceed with upgrading Sequelize without breaking too much? Because there is a lot of code and I really want to keep this as simple as possible, because a lot of errors arise when I try upgrading the Sequelize package.

Comment: does your project handling API routes?

Comment: Yes. The project is basically an API and a CMS